# React: How to return value from method of Context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I want to return a boolean value from a method within my Context, how would I do that?
My approach is obviously not correct. As a beginner I often get confused which syntax to use  where.

This is my ContextProvider:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AuthContext from './AuthContext';

// Then create a provider Component to update children Components once the user role changes
class AuthProvider extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
          role: "none" //roles: none, admin, kursleiter
      }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,
        isAuthenticated: () => {
          if (this.state.role == "kursleiter" || this.state.role == "admin") {
            return true
          }
          return false},
        setRole: (newRole) => this.setState({
            role: newRole
        })
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default AuthProvider
```

And this is where I want to use my boolean (see the if-Statement):

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import AuthContext from '../../AuthContext';

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (
            <AuthContext.Consumer>
                {(context) => (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    { context.isAuthenticated() == true ? true : null}
                  </React.Fragment>
                )}
            </AuthContext.Consumer>
        ) {
          return <Component {...props} />;
        } else {
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: why if statement empty ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use `useContext` hook, which lets you read the context and subscribe to its changes.

In this case you are interested in extracting the function `isAuthenticated` from the context and using it inside the render prop of `Route`:

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/",
              state: {
                from: props.location,
              },
            }}
          />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```